# apache-13 error appears at package lifecycle with maven

Tags: java, maven

I created a simple Maven project on a rasberry pi and my project connects to a mysql database to be able to insert in, so to handle the dependencies and the plugins I have this pom.xml but when I try to make mvn package I have the following error knowing that it worked a first time and that it did well insert in my database I tried to look at several examples on the internet without result. thank you in advance

The error:

> [ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.17 or
>   one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read
>   artifact  descriptor for
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:jar:2.17: 1  problem
>   was encountered while building the effective model for 
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:[unknown-version]
>   [ERROR] [FATAL] Non-parseable POM 
>   /home/pi/.m2/repository/org/apache/apache/13/apache-13.pom: comment 
>   started on line 3 and column 5 was not closed (position:
>   START_DOCUMENT  seen ...\ufffd\u63D\ufffd\u1\u4 
>   \ufffd\ufffd2/\ufffd\ufffd7\ufffd/\ufffd\u00\ufffd\ufffd\u3\u0 
>   \ufffd\n\u0\u0\ufffd\u3\u0
>
> \ufffd\u0\u0\ufffd\ufffd$\u40d\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\u40\ufffd\ufffd\u3\u0\u13\ufffdI\ufffd\ufffd\u1a\u0\u0U\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\u1au\ufffd...
>   @81:40) caused by: java.io.EOFException: no more data available
>   START_DOCUMENT seen ...\ufffd\u63D\ufffd\u1\u4
>   \ufffd\ufffd2/\ufffd\ufffd7\ufffd/\ufffd\u00\ufffd\ufffd\u3\u0
>   \ufffd\n\u0\u0\ufffd\u3\u0
>   \ufffd\u0\u0\ufffd\ufffd$\u40d\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\u40\ufffd\ufffd\u3\u0\u13\ufffdI\ufffd\ufffd\u1a\u0\u0U\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\u1au\ufffd...
>   @81:40 @ /home/pi/.m2/repository/org/apache/apache/13/apache-13.pom,
>   line 81,     column 40

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>csRunBI</groupId>
    <artifactId>csRunBi</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <jodatime.version>2.5</jodatime.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
            <type>maven-plugin</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>csRunProject</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <!-- Jar file entry point -->
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                            <classpathPrefix>dependency-jars/</classpathPrefix>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- exclude junit, we need runtime dependency only -->
                            <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dependency-jars/</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: what is the value of the property jdk.version?

Comment: alors j'ai la version 1.8.0_65 je ne sais pas si c'est cela que vous demandé

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please ask your question in English. If you are using french most of us can only guess what you are asking.

Comment: yes you are right I enclose the translation of my post :                                                                               I created a simple Maven project on a rasberry pi and my project connects to a mysql database to be able to insert in, so to handle the dependencies and the plugins I have this pom.xml but when I try to make mvn package I have the following error knowing that it worked a first time and that it did well insert in my database I tried to look at several examples on the internet without result. thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling the variable `jdk.version` with `${jdk.version}` you should define it in your `pom.xml`. You can simply add the new variable between your `<properties>...</properties>` tag like it:

```
<properties>
    <jodatime.version>2.5</jodatime.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
</properties>
```

You can read more about the pom properties: [pom properties documentation](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties)